# Finding all wanted words in a string

Tags: c++, string, search

I have a string which is too long, I want to find and locate all of the wanted words. For example I want to find the locations of all "apple"s in the string. Can you tell me how I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Look into boost::regex if you need to match more complex stuff. Otherwise, stick with Frerich Raabe's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apply repeatedly [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) if you are using C++ strings, or [`std::strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr) if you are using C strings; in both cases, at each iteration start to search n characters after the last match, where n is the length of your word.

```
std::string str="one apple two apples three apples";
std::string search="apple";
for(std::string::size_type pos=0; pos<str.size(); pos+=search.size())
{
    pos=str.find(search, pos);
    if(pos==std::string::npos)
        break;
    std::cout<<"Match found at: "<<pos<<std::endl;
}
```

([link](http://ideone.com/j2J2s))

Comment: This won't find the overlapping matches - e.g. for a pattern eye and string eyeye, all the answers given so far will only find the first occurrence.

Comment: I think this will break if the match is at the end of the string, e.g.  if `str` would end in `apple`. In that case, you would call `std::string::find(search, pos);` with a value of `pos` being equal to `size()`. Not sure that's allowed.

Comment: @IvanVergiliev: if that's desired or not depends on what specification you want to implement with this function (there are valid use cases for both specifications); still, all it's needed is to change `pos+=...` to `pos++`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: it's the same thing I thought, but I had to go before I checked the standard. Still, I'll add a quick check, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop which repeatedly calls `std::string::find`; on each iteration, you start finding beyond your last hit:

```
std::vector<std::string::size_type> indicesOf( const std::string &s,
                                               const std::string &needle )
{
  std::vector<std::string::size_type> indices;
  std::string::size_type p = 0;
  while ( p < s.size() ) {
    std::string::size_type q = s.find( needle, p );
    if ( q == std::string::npos ) {
      break;
    }
    indices.push_back( q );
    p = q + needle.size(); // change needle.size() to 1 for overlapping matches
  }
  return indices;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void findApples(const char* someString)
{
   const char* loc = NULL;
   while ((loc = strstr(someString, "apple")) != NULL) {
      // do something
      someString = loc + strlen("apple");
   }
}
```

Comment: Given that the qustion is about C++, I'd consider an answer about `std::string` to be more appropriate.