# Reaching the 3rd word in a string

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reaching a specific word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469591/reaching-a-specific-word-in-a-string)

I asked a very similar question but apparently I asked it wrong. The question is that I need to reach the 3rd word in a string in C++ and the string is like this:

> ```
> word1\tword2\tword3\tword4\tword5\tword6
> ```

word2 can have spaces inside.

I tried to read the string character by character but I found it inefficient. I tried code

```
std::istringstream str(array[i]); 
str >> temp >> temp >> word; 
array2[i] = word;
```

and it didn't work because of the spaces inside word2.

Can you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? You must have attempted something. Where did you get stuck? You obviously know what separates words. How did you search for those?

Comment: It's the third time you ask more or less the same question... just use e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11469613/214671) you already received! EDIT: or adapt a little [the code I wrote for you last time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362616/214671).

Comment: You're not showing us what you have tried though. Show us. Where are you stuck. It seems you got a solution to your previous question which should help you along.

Comment: word2 can have spaces inside? ..you are supposed to show us the actual string at least..

Comment: I tried to read the string character by character but I found it ineefficient. I tried 
`code`  std::istringstream str(array[i]);
  str >> temp >> temp >> word;
  array2[i] = word;
and it didn't work because of the spaces inside word2..

Comment: Why don't you simply look for the `'\t'` which apparently separates each "word" you're looking for? Content in between those should be a word as per your definition.

Comment: This is starting to look like a string of homework questions, designed to further the lesson with each task...

Comment: This is definitely not a homework. I'm not taking any programming course in summer. I'm just not good at coding so I asked for help.. And thanks for the help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    //input string:
    std::string str = "w o r d 1\tw o r d2\tword3\tword4";
    int wordStartPosition = 0;//The start of each word in the string

    for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )//looking for the third one (start counting from 0)
        wordStartPosition = str.find_first_of( '\t', wordStartPosition + 1 );

    //Getting where our word ends:
    int wordEndPosition = str.find_first_of( '\t', wordStartPosition + 1 );
    //Getting the desired word and printing:
    std::string result =  str.substr( wordStartPosition + 1, str.length() - wordEndPosition - 1 );
    std::cout << result;
}
```

output:

```
word3
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following example.
your third word is the 3rd item in the std::vector...

Create a split string function which splits a large string into an std::vector objects. use that std::vector to get your third string.

see the following example, try running in in an empty C++ console project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void splitString(std::string str, char token, std::vector<std::string> &words)
{
    std::string word = "";
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == token)
        {
            if( word.length() == 0 )
                continue;

            words.push_back(word);
            word = "";
            continue;
        }

        word.push_back( str[i] );
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string stream = "word1\tword2\tword3\tword4\tword5\tword6";

    std::vector<std::string> theWords;
    splitString( stream, '\t', theWords);

    for(int i=0; i<theWords.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", theWords[i].c_str() );
    }

    while(true){}
    return 0;
}
```